# Is there any way to obtain the fired row of the decision table in ODM 8.10?

Tags: rules, rule-engine, ibm-odm, jrules

I am using this way to obtain the rule name:

```
com.ibm.rules.engine.ruledef.runtime.Rule ruleFired = getRule();

java.lang.String ruleName = (java.lang.String) ruleFired .getName();
java.lang.System.out.println("ruleFired " + ruleName );

return ruleName;
```

But, I can not obtain the specific row fired for a descision table

Comment: Are you getting the rule name with suffix that indicates the row it fired? like decision_table_0, decision_table_1 etc.. ?

Comment: no, just the name of the table

Comment: You have to iterate the table in order to get a specific rule

Comment: Where is this code included in the rule app?  I'm trying to use the results from a getRule() like function, but I'm not sure how to implement it or where to put it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an observer using **RuleEngineObserver**
In the method

```
ruleExecutionStarted(Observable obs, RuleInstance rule)
```

The method : **rule.getRuleAction().getName()**  will provide the table row execution number when the rule is a decision table.

Best